# Elements invisible for no apparent reason in Safari only

Tags: html, css, safari

I have a site that works fine in Chrome, Firefox, IE7-11, android, iOS (both ipad and iphone) yet for some unknown reason all elements except the header and rotating banner are invisible in Safari and only Safari.

The elements are all present and when inspected the outlines of each individual elements appear.

If I disable CSS the elements all appear and are there.

As I scroll through the page, which for the post part is just blank white space occasionally some of the elements will reappear in a very glitchy way, perhaps just a thin vertical stripe of the element will be visible then it will disappear.

I can't make the site public at the moment, but here is a screenshot showing the issue:

[image: screenshot]

Has anyone had something similar happen before in Safari, or have any suggestions?

Comment: Any JSfiddle, code or live link may help

Comment: Is there any way I can share the link so that I can remove it after the question is answered?

Comment: Please isolate out only the code that is causing the issue.

Comment: @Zaqx I'm afraid I have no idea which part of the code is causing it. I've never seen anything like this happen before.

Comment: "I have no idea which part of the code is causing it" @Marc, in cases like this you start by removing things until the issue goes away. At that point back up until you see the issue again and try removing things from a different area. Keep going until you have the minimum code needed to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the div is hidden.

Add `z-index:1;` to the div with `tdp_row_fullwidth center-yes light-no` class and the div shows up in safari for me.

Comment: Thank you :) Really appreciate that. The layout seems a bit screwed up, not sure why that is, but at least I can see what's going now.

Comment: Thanks for taking a second look.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. How come only Safari hides it?

Comment: I have a similar issue but this doesn't work for me... but if I change/remove ANY css property and then change it back, it shows. So Safari just needs to recalculate something but isn't. Is that a different issue?

Comment: This fixed a similar issue for me even though no surrounding elements are using z-index. Very strange.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was the font-family that was being used was not loaded in Safari, once I changed it, the element "showed" up.